# Unable to get values in Item Added event receiver

Tags: 2013, event-receivers, splistitem

I have created an event receiver which will be executing after the item is added to the list.

I want to make the sub site based on the values entered in the list.

My event receiver code is:

```
    public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.ItemAdded(properties);

        SPListItem item = properties.ListItem;
        string url = Convert.ToString(item[FieldNames.Url]);
        string title =Convert.ToString(item[FieldNames.ProjectName]);
        string desc = Convert.ToString(item[FieldNames.AboutProject]);
        SPWeb web = properties.Site.AllWebs.Add(url, title, desc, 1033, "Lf.Int#4", false, false);
        web.Dispose();            
    }
```

In code `FieldName` class properties are for getting the internal names of fields.

I debugged the program and found `url=""` `title=""` `desc=""` i.e. I am not getting any value through item object. All things are null.

What am I missing?

Comment: Items in the list is being added from visual web part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to be sure, try to get the values from **ItemUpdated** event. Maybe the reason why that the values are not available is because they aren't exist yet.

Comment: @users1100, Did you get the values in ItemUpdated.?

Comment: Yes,there was matter with the item adding. I added item values from visual web part and while adding event I used `ListItem item  = list.AddItem();` instead I did `item=list.Items.Add()`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not using internal names of the fields in the code. The follwoing post shows how to get internal names of the fields:

http://www.idubbs.com/blog/2012/finding-internal-names-for-sharepoint-list-columns/

Comment: Tried using internal name also but still all values are null

Answer (score 0):

Remove `base.ItemAdded(properties);` and try `properties.ListItem["InternalName"]`

Comment: Thank you for reply sir, tried your way also but not working

Comment: Can you try in item adding? let me know if it gives values there.

Answer (score 0):

You can check using **properties.ListTitle** to confirm whether this event fires when you add entry into your list. Because this event is common and it will be called for every list.

Comment: Yes, I am sure that the event is firing because I debugging it in Visual Studio by attaching process w3wp :-)

Comment: Whether your properties has values for any columns in the list?

Comment: try setting EventFiringEnabled = false; before base.ItemAdded(properties); and EventFiringEnabled = true; at the end of the ItemAdded function.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the

```
properties.AfterProperties["InternalColumnName"]
```

Ref: [List Before and After properties](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/4223/)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Tried `AfterProperties` also sir.

Comment: The values to the list is being added via visual web part, can it create problem

Comment: @users1100, are you getting the ID value for `properties.ListItemId` ?

Comment: Yes I can get item using the ListItemId